# How to set a variable to something once when re-running code in python

Tags: python, arrays, append

```
accounts = []
no = input(' do you already have an account')
if no =='no':
  print('please answer a few questions to create an account')
  usersetup = input('what would you like your username to be ')
  psetup = input('What would you like your password to be ')
  accounts.append([usersetup,psetup])
  import pickle
  dataset =  accounts
  outputFile = 'accounts.data'
  fw = open(outputFile, 'wb')
  pickle.dump(dataset, fw)
  fw.close()
```

The problem is everytime I run the code accounts gets set to a list containing nothing so none of the information I add is saved. How do I fix this.

Comment: Could you post more of your code? It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: You have to save the data somewhere outside the program (e.g. in the file you're creating). Then, the next time the program runs, you need to retrieve that data (e.g. read from the file you wrote to last time).

In general it's not possible to make a self-contained program that remembers its state from run to run - you have to have a file or database on the outside that it can refer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the pickled file - using `pickle.load`:

```
import pickle    

input = open('accounts.data', 'r')
accounts = pickle.load(input)
```

Comment: Adam, Thank you for answering my question. However, when I implemented your suggestion I received the following error:   accounts = pickle.load('accounts.data')
NameError: name 'pickle' is not defined If I import pickle before issuing the argument I receive this error: accounts = pickle.load('accounts.data')
TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
ERROR: Module: test could not be imported

Comment: Hi Alex, you need to put the `import pickle` at the top of the file, so that your script knows about `pickle` when you call it.

Comment: If I import pickle before issuing the argument I receive this error: accounts = pickle.load('accounts.data') TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes ERROR: Module: test could not be imported

Comment: I've just made a change - apologies, you need to call a file object in your `pickle.load()` call.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries, feel free to ask anything else. Note, that if you haven't already made `accounts.data` already, your script will error when you try to `open('accounts.data')` - you can wrap around a `try: except:` block if required.